# Return two different things inside same return in JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

There is a service which gets the data and has a then-catch structure:

```
getData(siteId) {
        const accessToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ls.authorizationData')).token;
        const config = { ...
        };

        this.canceler.resolve();
        this.canceler = this.$q.defer();
        config.timeout = this.canceler.promise;

        const siteIds = this.MyService.getSitesIds();
        return this.$http.get(`${TEST_API_URL}value?siteIds=${siteId || siteIds}`, config)
        .then(result => {
            return {
                data: result.data,
            };
        }).catch((e) => {
            if (e.status === -1 && e.xhrStatus === "abort") {
                return Promise.resolve({canceled: true});
            }
            debugger;
            this.hasData = false;
            return Promise.reject('Cannot access data ');
        });
    }
```

I'm calling this function from the controller, initially in `$onInit()` like this:

```
$onInit() {
    getData.call(null, this);
}
```

and as a function:

```
function getData(MyCtrl) {
    MyCtrl.loading = true;
    MyCtrl.MyService.getData(MyCtrl.siteId).then(result => {
        if (result.canceled) {
            return;
        }

...
}
```

This works fine.

The problem appears when I want to send a variable from service to controller if data is not there (if the `catch()` happens).

I tried to change the return by wrapping the Promise inside an object like

`return {promise: Promise.reject('Cannot access data ')};` 
and add the variable inside this object:

```
return {promise: Promise.reject('Cannot access data ')
         hasData: false};
```

but it seems that it's not the right way. I need to know in the controller if the data was got or not.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `return {'promise': Promise.reject('Boo'), 'hasData' : false}` ?

Comment: can't you just return false in case of failure and work with if (fn(...) === false) ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you want to return more data from a Promise rejection, you do it the same way you would return from a normal exception, you extend from the Error object.

Here is an example..

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (message, extra) {
    super(message);
    this.extra = extra;
  }
}

//standard promise rejection way.
function badPromise() {
  return Promise.reject(
    new MyError("Bad Error", "Extra Stuff")
  );
}

//works if throw error inside an async function
async function badPromise2() {
  throw new MyError("Bad Error2", "Extra Stuff2");
}

async function test() {
  try {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) await badPromise();
    else await badPromise2();
  } catch(e) {
    if (e instanceof MyError) {
      console.error(`${e.message}, extra = ${e.extra}`);
    } else {
      console.error(`${e.toString()}`);
    }
  }
}

test();
```

ps. This is using new ESNext features, but the same applies if doing ES5..